# Why g++ still optimizes tail recursion when the recursion function result is multiplied?

Tags: c++, assembly, optimization, g++, tail-recursion

They say, the tail recursion optimization works only when the the call is just before return from the function. So they show this code as example of what shouldn't be optimized by C compilers:

```c++
long long f(long long n) {
    return n > 0 ? f(n - 1) * n : 1;
}
```

because there the recursive function call is multiplied by `n` which means the last operation is multiplication, not recursive call. However, it *is* even on `-O1` level:

```asm
recursion`f:
    0x100000930 <+0>:  pushq  %rbp
    0x100000931 <+1>:  movq   %rsp, %rbp
    0x100000934 <+4>:  movl   $0x1, %eax
    0x100000939 <+9>:  testq  %rdi, %rdi
    0x10000093c <+12>: jle    0x10000094e               
    0x10000093e <+14>: nop    
    0x100000940 <+16>: imulq  %rdi, %rax
    0x100000944 <+20>: cmpq   $0x1, %rdi
    0x100000948 <+24>: leaq   -0x1(%rdi), %rdi
    0x10000094c <+28>: jg     0x100000940               
    0x10000094e <+30>: popq   %rbp
    0x10000094f <+31>: retq
```

They say that:

> Your final rules are therefore sufficiently correct. However, return `n
>   * fact(n - 1)` does have an operation in the tail position! This is the multiplication `*`, which will be the last thing the function does
>   before it returns. In some languages, this might actually be
>   implemented as a function call which could then be tail-call
>   optimized.

However, as we see from ASM listing, multiplication is still an ASM instruction, not a separate function. So I really struggle to see difference with accumulator approach:

```c++
int fac_times (int n, int acc) {
    return (n == 0) ? acc : fac_times(n - 1, acc * n);
}

int factorial (int n) {
    return fac_times(n, 1);
}
```

This produces

```asm
recursion`fac_times:
    0x1000008e0 <+0>:  pushq  %rbp
    0x1000008e1 <+1>:  movq   %rsp, %rbp
    0x1000008e4 <+4>:  testl  %edi, %edi
    0x1000008e6 <+6>:  je     0x1000008f7               
    0x1000008e8 <+8>:  nopl   (%rax,%rax)
    0x1000008f0 <+16>: imull  %edi, %esi
    0x1000008f3 <+19>: decl   %edi
    0x1000008f5 <+21>: jne    0x1000008f0               
    0x1000008f7 <+23>: movl   %esi, %eax
    0x1000008f9 <+25>: popq   %rbp
    0x1000008fa <+26>: retq
```

Am I missing something? Or it's just compilers became smarter?

Comment: whoever "they" are, they're wrong.

Comment: Of course, `f(n-1)*n` is `n*f(n-1)`. I don't see how this comes as a surprise.

Comment: gcc is smarter than "they"

Comment: @MSalters I'm not surprised about multiplication commutativity as it's the basic math rule. My question was why is this optimized when the actual result is not a recursive function call result, but multiplication (since you put operands first, one of which is recursive call, and then you do multiplication over them, i. e. `a f() *` in postfix notation). This was a surprise for my colleagues as well. But it seems if a math action is done between function call and a *constant*, it is an easy task for optimizer.

Comment: What is the source of the quotes, i.e. who is "they"?  To me, it seems like the optimizer is at least smarter than your source...

Comment: @anderas I'm referring to this post (http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/307040), however I found this thought in various sources (e.g. tutorials, wikis). At least I can say, that if the result is multiplied by a variable, then the tail recursion really isn't optimized. However, if it's multiplied by a constant as in example, it does, despite some say it won't.

Answer (score 1):

As you see in the assembly code, the compiler is smart enough to turn your code into a loop that is basically equivalent to (disregarding the different data types):

```
int fac(int n)
{
    int result = n;
    while (--n)
        result *= n;
    return result;
}
```

GCC is smart enough to know that the state needed by each call to your original `f` can be kept in two variables (`n` and `result`) through the whole recursive call sequence, so that no stack is necessary. It can transform `f` to `fac_times`, and both to `fac`, so to say. This is most likely not only a result of tail call optimization in the strictest sense, but one of the loads of other heuristics that GCC uses for optimization.

*(I can't go more into detail regarding the specific heuristics that are used here since I don't know enough about them.)*

Comment: As I said above, I'm not surprised about multiplication commutativity as it's the basic math rule. My question was why is this optimized when the actual result is not a recursive function call result, but multiplication (since you put operands first, one of which is recursive call, and then you do multiplication over them, i. e. `a f() *` in postfix notation). This was a surprise for my colleagues as well. But it seems if a math action is done between function call and a *constant*, it is an easy task for optimizer.

Comment: @efpies after reading the programmers.SE post, I think i got your point. Re-worded the answer to at least make clear that this likely isn't only a matter of tail call optimization.

Answer (score 1):

The non-accumulator `f` isn't tail-recursive.  The compiler's options include turning it into a loop by transforming it, or `call` / some insns / `ret`, but they don't include `jmp f` without other transformations.

tail-call optimization applies in cases like this:

```
int ext(int a);
int foo(int x) { return ext(x); }
```

asm output from [godbolt](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#%7B%22version%22%3A3%2C%22filterAsm%22%3A%7B%22labels%22%3Atrue%2C%22directives%22%3Atrue%2C%22commentOnly%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22compilers%22%3A%5B%7B%22sourcez%22%3A%22JYOwLgBApgHmAUpIEMCUBuAUEiAzA9vouBDKhAN4QBOUYArtSNHPGehAL5AAAA%3D%3D%22%2C%22compiler%22%3A%22clang380%22%2C%22options%22%3A%22-xc%20-O3%20-Wall%20-mtune%3Dhaswell%22%7D%5D%7D):

```
foo:                                    # @foo
        jmp     ext                     # TAILCALL
```

Tail-call optimization means leaving a function (or recursing) with a `jmp` instead of a `ret`.  Anything else is *not* tailcall optimization.  Tail-recursion that's optimized with a `jmp` really is a loop, though.

A good compiler will do further transformations to put the conditional branch at the bottom of the loop when possible, removing the unconditional branch.  (In asm, the `do{}while()` style of looping is the most natural).